# How to change sign among eight octants

Tags: plotting

```
r[th_] = 2 Cos[th]^2 + Sin[th]^2; z[th_] = Cos[th] Sin[th]; 
Eq ={r[th] Cos[th + v], z[th], r[th] Sin[th + v]}; 
TR = .025; 
thmax =Pi/3; 
UU =Show[Table[ParametricPlot3D[Eq {1, 1, 1}, {th, 0,
     thmax}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Tube[TR]}], {v, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/18}]];
UX = Show[    Table[ParametricPlot3D[Eq {-1, 1, 1}, {th, 0, thmax}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Tube[TR]}], {v, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/18}]];
U3 = Show[    Table[ParametricPlot3D[Eq {-1, -1, 1}, {th, 0, thmax}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Tube[TR]}], {v, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/18}]]; 
UY = Show[    Table[ParametricPlot3D[Eq {1, -1, 1}, {th, 0, thmax}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Tube[TR]}], {v, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/18}]]; 
UUN = Show[    Table[ParametricPlot3D[Eq {1, 1, -1}, {th, 0, thmax}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Tube[TR]}], {v, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/18}]]; 
UXN = Show[    Table[ParametricPlot3D[Eq {-1, 1, -1}, {th, 0, thmax}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Tube[TR]}], {v, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/18}]]; 
U3N = Show[    Table[ParametricPlot3D[Eq {-1, -1, -1}, {th, 0, thmax}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Tube[TR]}], {v, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/18}]]; 
UYN = Show[    Table[ParametricPlot3D[Eq {1, -1, -1}, {th, 0, thmax}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Tube[TR]}], {v, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/18}]]; 
asympt = Show[{UU, UX, U3, UY, UUN, UXN, U3N, UYN},
PlotRange -> All,PlotLabel -> Gold_Tired 
]
```

Please, show how to include all eight signs in the last symmetrical Show.

Also please indicate how to neatly separate lines that are okay in my listing before pasting here.

Answer (score 1):

This may be more concise but probably not as efficient (using `r[th]` as defined:

```
Eq[th_, v_] := {r[th] Cos[th + v], z[th], r[th] Sin[th + v]};
TR = .025;
thmax = Pi/3;
tup = Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3];
rn = Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/18];
With[{fun = Times @@@ Tuples[{tup, (Eq[th, #] & /@ rn)}]}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[fun, {th, 0, thmax}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Yellow, Tube[TR]}}]]
```